# Very strange accuracy change?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, catboost

Below is my catboost model:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
cb_model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=500,
                             learning_rate=0.05,
                             depth=10,
                             random_seed = 42,
                             bagging_temperature = 0.2,
                             od_type='Iter',
                             metric_period = 50,
                             od_wait=20)
cb_model.fit(X, y)
r2_score(cb_model.predict(X), y)
```

The output is: `0.9999993582437351`

When I try and print a confusion matrix:

```
classificationSummary(y, clf.predict(X))
```

the output consistently becomes the following:

```
Confusion Matrix (Accuracy 0.9700)

       Prediction
Actual  0  1
     0 50  1
     1  2 47
```

Why does the accuracy decrease?

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be two different `accuracy` and you can't compare them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not an issue, and it comes from a fundamental misunderstanding of the underlying problem and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong metric. r2_score calculates r squared or [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), this is used for regression and not for calculating accuracy.

You should use [accuracy score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)